# .htaccess rewrite / accept language

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

following problem:
I have 2 html sites in subfolders, one site in English and one in German. I use .htaccess rewrite rule to redirect to the right site based on the language of the user:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

This is the code in the .htaccess in the subfolder of the English version.
The problem occurs when a German user wants to view the English version of the page, he always gets redirected to the German version.

Is there any way to redirect the user on the first visit, but when he clicks on the hyperlink `English` on the German page, he gets to see the English version, without being redirected again to the German site?

mod-rewrite is available but I need a condition to redirect only once (on first visit) and when the user clicks a specific hyperlink, he wont get redirected again?

Comment: then you have to create code for that instead of define in .htaccess file.

Comment: what type of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea, if you have two subdirectores, e.g. `de` and `en`, you could rewrite instead of redirect based on `Accept-Language` header. But if the browser requests an explicit path including the language prefix, it won't be redirected.

- http://www.example.com/page1.html will show `/en/page1.html` or `/de/page1.html` depending on `Accept-Language`
- http://www.example.com/en/page1.html will always show `/en/page1.html` no matter what `Accept-Language` says

You could try these (untested!) rules

```
RewriteRule ^en/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^de/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /de%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

---

Another approach could be to set a cookie, when the user decides on a language, and deliver pages according to this cookie.